# Help with understanding why this rewrite doesn't work?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this:

```
 RewriteRule ^show_shop/([0-9]+)$ show_shop.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

When entering the url like this: "domain.com/show_shop/4" then the url is fetched, and "show_shop.php" is displayed. So the rewrite kindof works.

However, the nr behind the slash doesnt work. I use this code:

```
  $id = $_GET['id'];
```

but it results in blank, ie nothing is there. It isn't set according to php.

What could be the cause of this.

FYI I have plenty of other rules just like this, and they work fine, but this one seems to be troublesome...

Entering the URL manually (the real url) like this "show_shop.php?id=4" works fine, and the id is GET and all is fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: dump out $_SERVER and $_REQUEST to see where the id is getting dropped.

Comment: Seriously, this has **absolutely nothing** to do with security.   Also you might have better luck on serverfault,  no joke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the QSA-Flag

```
RewriteRule ^show_shop/([0-9]+)$ show_shop.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be % rather than $

```
RewriteRule ^show_shop/([0-9]+)$ show_shop.php?id=%1 [NC]
```